# How can I secure a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, security

There is a database with different tables for a mobile phone application.
UserIds are stored in the table for each row. Only these users should be allowed to read these data sets. Is this technically possible? If yes, how can I implement this?

I have a smartphone app where users can register to access the self created data. But I want to avoid a security hole that allows access to the whole table.

Edit: Correct text

Comment: Have you consider multitenancy?

Comment: Your application code needs to check on every SQL statement that the rows selected belong to the username using the device. `WHERE .... AND userid=?` Under no circumstance should your mobile application allow any sort of direct access to the database or query development.

Comment: @LucaRiccitelli Do you mean that i create a table for every new user and give permissions?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes I know, but if the user maybe get the link from the database he can see all rows...Normaly there is no way in the application to see all but if he know the link and maybe the credentials it is possible

Comment: There should be no way for the user of the mobile app to see the database ever. A mobile app that connects to a database should connect through a server application over HTTPS web services - so phone --> server application --> database. The phone can only act as a client of the server with the credential of the mobile user. The server sends queries to the database, limiting to data accessible to that user. Under no circumstance should the database be network accessible to the mobile devices, only to the application server.